# Inferring parameter list of function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm struggling with typing my function creator. I'd expect the `putDefaultKey` to have arguments of the passed functions. Having them as an object would be fine, too.

```js
const operator = (key: string, value: any) => null

type KeyCreator<G extends any[]> = (...args: G) => string

const createPut = <v, G extends any[] = []>(
  operator: (key: string, value: v) => void,
  key: KeyCreator<G>,
) => {
  return (value: v, ...args: Parameters<KeyCreator<G>>) =>
    operator(key(...args), value)
}

const putDefaultKey = createPut<string>(
  operator,
  (a: string, b: string) => 'something' + a + b,
)

// expected way to call
putDefaultKey('value', 'a string', 'b string')

// having them as an object
putDefaultKey('value', {
  a: 'a string',
  b: 'b string',
})
```

The parameters of `putDefaultKey` are just described as `value: string, ...args: any[]` however I'd expect it to be `value: string, a: string, b: string`

[image]

Comment: your code contains syntax errors, could you please fix them? Please provide `operator` variable and `op` variable

Comment: ✔ done. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: No problem. Please provide what return type do you expect from `createPut`. You probably want to infer provided arguments and convert them to some value. How do you want to infer `operator`? DO you need to infer operator `key` and `value`?

Comment: I'm trying to "merge" the parameter list of the `KeyCreator` and my created function (that takes `value` the first argument). I added more details to the question. I hope that makes my challenge more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was trying to infer all arguments:

```js
const operator = <Value,>(key: string, value: Value) => null

const createPut = <Value, Arg, Args extends Arg[]>(
  operator: (key: string, value: Value) => void,
  key: (...args: [...Args]) => string,
) =>
  (value: Value, ...args: [...Args]) =>
    operator(key(...args), value)

const putDefaultKey = createPut(
  operator,
  <A extends string, B extends string>(a: A, b: B): `something ${A} ${B}` => `something ${a} ${b}`,
)

// value: string, a: string, b: string
putDefaultKey('value', 'a string', 'b string')
```

In order to infer rest parameters `...args` it is worth using [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types)

More about inference of function arguments you can find in my [article](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments)

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.0-beta#code/MYewdgzgLgBCAOBTATgQyiZMC8MA8AaqgDYCuiANAHwAUA1ogJ4BcM0yAlmAOYUwBuJcqyJlEAShxUYYUsWIAoBaEixgyROkQAFUrFyEhlGAEFkvU%20YgxEADyiIwAE2tnuAbQC6tBTDhI0DGRWeiZWdi4LQTERI0lsaX4QDicKXxgGFhgaADo81CtWdzyctwhPeOkInjTK9Jpo4RhRcj4Sgu4IIpKyiql0vwQUdExQxlz8q3E%20RoklFWgYeD0AEUQAM1Q5KABpJhwYdU0HXSgadKHAzDS-PBMbe0cXNihOGpgAIQeHZ2tq7loqFYJj4ACNWB9xKwAAYQEAAW0QUAAFpEYAASADeJgAvhjMR8cdCpDBYQikaiePjUHisaCibUlAB6JkCIzhV6RPhAl5vCzg3mRBTLKBrTbbPbjADksylfClqEFPDlMCloKV3Cl4gUQA)

With explicit generic:

```js
const operator = <Value,>(key: string, value: Value) => null

const createPut = <Value,>() =>
  <Arg, Args extends Arg[]>(
    operator: <T>(key: string, value: Value) => void,
    key: (...args: [...Args]) => string,
  ) =>
    (value: Value, ...args: [...Args]) =>
      operator(key(...args), value)

const putWithNumber = createPut<number>()

const putDefaultKey = putWithNumber(
  operator,
  (a: string, b: string) => `something ${a} ${b}`,
)

putDefaultKey(1, 'a string', 'b string') // ok
putDefaultKey('str', 'a string', 'b string') // error
```

Comment: Great! [This is what I was looking for](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.0-beta#code/MYewdgzgLgBCAOBTATgQyiZMC8MA8AaqgDYCuiANAHwAUA1ogJ4BcM0yAlmAOYUwBuJcqyJlEAShxUYYUsWIAoBaEixgyROkQAFUrFyEhlGAEFkvU+YgxEADyiIwAE2tnuAbQC6tBTDhI0DGRWeiZWdi4LQTERI0lsaX4QDicKXxgGFhgaADo81CtWdzyctwhPeOkInjTK9Jpo4RhRcj4Sgu4IIpKyiql0vwQUdExQxlz8q3E+RoklFWgYeD0AEUQAM1Q5KABpJhwYdU0HXSgadKHAzDS-GlRwqE4amAAjB6fuSpgAAwgQAFtEFAABaRGAAEgA3qgAL4QyEvGHfWpKZZQNabbZ7cYARj4AHJUGxHpF8QSXsSPvjxEoFEA). One thing is left: Is it possible to explicitly type Value when calling createPut?

Comment: do you want to infer it as literal type `1`  instead of just a `number`?

Comment: No – I'd like to be able to explicitly type `createPut<string>` (or s.th. like `createPut<MyCustomType>`) so the created function expects a `string` (or whatever typed as) as a `value` argument.

Comment: There is a way, but you need to create extra function for `Value` generic. I made an update. Btw, it is better to let TS to infer all generic arguments